# How does this proof about the the coloring of a Graph work?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, coloring

Could someone tell me how this [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncRc3.jpg) works (Statement $\chi(G)=\max \{\chi(B) : B \subset G\}$, especially what is the induction hypothesis and why is this proof working?
Does this proof only work on a  not connected Graph too?
I'm trying to learn something about graphs and coloring, but this kind of induction without the classic structure is new for me.

Comment: A proof without the statement of what is proved is pretty useless. What proof is this?

Comment: Why have you removed reference to the theorem and the proof?  This makes the question and answer useless to others!

Comment: It's clear that you have not been properly taught induction. Please read [this](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10034/1550) carefully, and the first half of [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10033/1550). As stated in the second post, one cannot truly understand induction unless one first understands basic first-order logic, so you'd need to learn logic if you want true understanding of induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is made in two parts, first to  show $\max{\chi(B)}\leq\chi(G)$ and second to show there exists a graph colouring such that $\max{\chi(B)=\chi(G)}$, leaving the theorem.

The  first part is straightforward: a full graph colouring with more colours than those needed for its largest block can have the extra colours "culled" down to fit.

---

The second part is done by induction. The base case is the trivial case of a graph with one block (result by definition).

It is then shown, if you start with a graph with multiple blocks where the property holds, you can reduce the number of blocks by one to get another graph where the property holds.

If you then "fiddle" with the colours of the reduced graph, you can add back the block you removed, getting back the original graph, now with a colouring where the property holds.

Since this applies inductively, you could theoretically work "back down to" the trivial case, and then rebuild the original graph, to get a colouring that does what you want.

Note that the proof is existential, not constructive, so it only shows *that* you can, *not how* you can.

Comment: Hello, but where is the induction hypothesis ? Sry for this maybe dumb question but I'm not a student, just learning it by my self.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is always whatever you are trying to show. In this case, it's that the graph colouring number can be the same as the largest block colouring number.

Comment: Ahh ok, one last question, does this proof work also with a not connected Graph and why?

Comment: If the graph wasn't connected, the other part would form a new block, so it's a graph with multiple blocks, so the proof applies the same.